# Editing voices in video game

Tags: editing, voice, video, game

Hello,

I have been proposed to editing of voices for a video game (on protools), knowing that I come from the cinema, the timing and amount of files are not the same, do you have any advice or working methods ?
And what kind of plugins do you use ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What is you mandate, to simply edit, tops and tails or do you also need to rename or master the files? Your workflow will change considerably considering what you need to do :) If you're steering clear of levels you may also want to consider a stereo editor, much faster to fly through files with key commands. Pro Tools is great if you need to do multiple tasks, which require automation and a way to layer your history.

As far as plug-ins goes nothing really comes to mind for editing, you'll need to become familiar with your trim selection and fade key commands though ;P

Let me know if you have any additional questions regarding this!

Alex

Comment: I don't know more by now, I guess I'll just edit and master files. By seeing your name, I have just realized that I know you, I worked with your colleague (Steven). It is funny that we find ourselves here ! Thank you for your answer ;)

Comment: Good to know! It's a small, but tight knit community. Stay in touch :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Alexander Saba that there are a few factors that need to be considered before deciding on the how to tackle the files. Quantity of files is a major factor here, also the playback behavior, e.g. whether they are randomly fired in the game or if there is a sequencial order to the dialogue. Another factor, is the quality and consistency the original recordings, sometimes the dialogue has been recorded with months apart sometimes in different studios and are supposed to sit back to back in game. Other things to consider is how much processing is being done in engine in what you need to add into the file yourself. OK having said all that here is my 2 cents.

If there are not so many files, the dialogue needs to fit in a narrative flow, there is a lot of detailed editing work/plugin work or you have just the raw recordings use Pro Tools and just bite the bullet with the amount time it takes to render them out at the end.

If you have thousands of files which have been basically edited and named but need leveling and basic trimming I use Izotope RX2 advanced (I used to use sound forge but prefer the sound of RX). I personally don't batch unless I am really 100% confident of the results, I prefer to listen and edit each file individually - this takes a lot more time but also means that your not going to get any embarrassing bad edits into the game.